# xcode8.1:invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug

Tags: ios, xib

I write the code below:

```
JSImgDeleteCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:displayCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and before use it,I registered it:

```
[_displayImgCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:displayCellID bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:displayCellID];
```

it is allright in xcode7.3,
but when I run this in xcode8.1,there is sth wrong,the msg like this:

invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.

```
libsystem_c.dylib`__abort:
    0x18ce163ec <+0>:   adrp   x8, 150192
    0x18ce163f0 <+4>:   add    x8, x8, #0                ; =0 
    0x18ce163f4 <+8>:   ldr    x9, [x8, #8]
    0x18ce163f8 <+12>:  cbnz   x9, 0x18ce16408           ; <+28>
    0x18ce163fc <+16>:  adrp   x9, 27
    0x18ce16400 <+20>:  add    x9, x9, #1393             ; =1393 
    0x18ce16404 <+24>:  str    x9, [x8, #8]
    0x18ce16408 <+28>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-32]!
    0x18ce1640c <+32>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #16]
    0x18ce16410 <+36>:  add    x29, sp, #16              ; =16 
    0x18ce16414 <+40>:  sub    sp, sp, #32               ; =32 
    0x18ce16418 <+44>:  add    x8, sp, #16               ; =16 
    0x18ce1641c <+48>:  add    x19, x8, #8               ; =8 
    0x18ce16420 <+52>:  movn   w20, #0
    0x18ce16424 <+56>:  stp    xzr, x20, [sp, #16]
    0x18ce16428 <+60>:  orr    w0, wzr, #0x6
    0x18ce1642c <+64>:  add    x1, sp, #16               ; =16 
    0x18ce16430 <+68>:  movz   x2, #0
    0x18ce16434 <+72>:  bl     0x18cdc552c               ; sigaction
    0x18ce16438 <+76>:  ldr    w8, [sp, #24]
    0x18ce1643c <+80>:  and    w8, w8, #0xffffffdf
    0x18ce16440 <+84>:  str    w8, [sp, #24]
    0x18ce16444 <+88>:  str    w20, [sp, #12]
    0x18ce16448 <+92>:  orr    w0, wzr, #0x3
    0x18ce1644c <+96>:  add    x1, sp, #12               ; =12 
    0x18ce16450 <+100>: movz   x2, #0
    0x18ce16454 <+104>: bl     0x18ce2b814               ; symbol stub for: __printf_arginfo_n
    0x18ce16458 <+108>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x1
    0x18ce1645c <+112>: bl     0x18cf6a470               ; __pthread_workqueue_setkill
    0x18ce16460 <+116>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x3
    0x18ce16464 <+120>: mov    x1, x19
    0x18ce16468 <+124>: movz   x2, #0
    0x18ce1646c <+128>: bl     0x18cf6885c               ; pthread_sigmask
    0x18ce16470 <+132>: bl     0x18cf6d908               ; pthread_self
    0x18ce16474 <+136>: orr    w1, wzr, #0x6
    0x18ce16478 <+140>: bl     0x18cf6a3e0               ; pthread_kill
    0x18ce1647c <+144>: movz   w0, #0x2710
    0x18ce16480 <+148>: bl     0x18cdf2b1c               ; usleep$NOCANCEL
    0x18ce16484 <+152>: orr    w8, wzr, #0xffffffe7
    0x18ce16488 <+156>: str    w8, [sp, #24]
    0x18ce1648c <+160>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x3
    0x18ce16490 <+164>: mov    x1, x19
    0x18ce16494 <+168>: movz   x2, #0
    0x18ce16498 <+172>: bl     0x18ce2b814               ; symbol stub for: __printf_arginfo_n
->  0x18ce1649c <+176>: brk    #0x1
```

please help!

Comment: did you use camera or another apple apis ?

Answer (score 11):

I had faced the same issue

CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.

But I found this is not the real reason behind crashing the app, the real reason i found below the above message as **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102ed2fb0'** on console 
is real reason.
So, I handle the null value which i received from backend.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I accidentally added two reference to the same Xib constraint. Removed one and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

sorry,it's just the index lost and Apple changed the error log,just add the .m file

Comment: can you elaborate on this more? I have no idea what your answer means?