# I can't get the switch to work without som kind of error massage. Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So here is all the code. I could not get it to work in my project, so I made  a new file just for this. The same problem was was still there.

**The CODE**

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  tester2
//
//  Created by x on 2020-01-13.
//  Copyright © 2020 x. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func switchOne(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if (sender.isOn)
            {
               view.backgroundColor = .white
            } else {              
               view.backgroundColor = .blue
            }
    }
}
```

**This is the result**

2020-01-13 18:59:55.071016+0100 tester2[44020:1745374] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.

So my question is how do I get this to work without the "invalid mode"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397425/xcode8-1invalid-mode-kcfrunloopcommonmodes-provided-to-cfrunlooprunspecific/41630644

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xcode8.1:invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on \_CFRunLoopError\_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397425/xcode8-1invalid-mode-kcfrunloopcommonmodes-provided-to-cfrunlooprunspecific)

Comment: Hi, No my "app" is running. But you get that massage.